# How to force gradle to build my app, even with errors (root)?

Tags: android, gradle

### What I have been doing

My app accesses many packages that Android Studio and Gradle denote as errors. However, my app has system privileges and has access to all of these during runtime, such as android.os.SystemProperties

Up until now, I have been compiling and installing this application to my device with:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch my_device_name
mm 
adb install path_to_apk_generated_with_mm
```

Using this method, I compile the app with mm and directly install it using adb without having to use gradle.

_

### What I'm looking for

Because I know that my app will run on my device, is there a way I can force gradle to build it and ignore what it thinks are errors? I would really like to be able to run my app directly from android studio, and more importantly,

*I'd like to start making use of android tests*

I can't generate an androidTest apk with mm and Gradle won't let me build the apk because it just throws errors.

Is there any way to make gradle build even with errors?

Comment: What kind of error ?

Comment: @ToYonos The error is "error: cannot find symbol" ... when I use things such as android.os.ServiceManager and android.os.SystemProperties (My app is a system app, so I need these, and they work in runtime, but android studio flags them as an error)

Comment: "However, my app has system privileges and has access to all of these during runtime" -- having "system privileges" has nothing to do with this. "is there a way I can force gradle to build it and ignore what it thinks are errors?" - no, because they are errors. The symbols that you are trying to access do not exist in the Android SDK; by default, they exist only in a full firmware build. It is conceivable that, as part of your custom firmware, that you remove the `@hide` annotations from things that you need, build a custom SDK, and try teaching Gradle to compile against it.